# Changes done in IIS Manager are reflected in web.config intead of applicationHost.config

Tags: iis-7.5, iis, isapi

I had to install a third party product on my server. Somehow this tool changed stuff in the IIS Settings and now for example when I add ISAPI Filter to a Web Site it stores the setting in the web.config file of of the Web Site instead in the applicationHost.config.

How can I configure it back that settings are stored again in the applicationHost.config ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, some settings just *do* live in web.config rather than applicationHost.config.  Stuff that tells IIS where your sites are end up in applicationHost -- once it knows that, it can pull site-specific settings from web.config.  I *think* it depends on the component, of course, and how it chooses to implement IAppHostWritableAdminManager (http://forums.iis.net/t/1041000.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third party product changed Feature Delegation for ISAPI Filters from ReadOnly to Read/Write. That change instructs IIS Manager to store the value in the web.config instead of applicationHost.config.